# T-SQL Derived Column in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
INT_VALUE = NULL -- Result Data Type = INT
,STR_VALUE = NULL -- Result Data Type = INT
```

I want to make sure that STR_VALUE is a varchar NULL and not int NULL. I need this to be done in SELECT statement and in derived column.

How can I achieve that?

Thank you

UPDATE: Thanks guys for really quick feedback. just "fyi" kind of thing, I am trying to create a lookup query for an ETL app and wanted to see if I could create NULL string column in t-sql rather than creating an ETL app based NULL string derived column.

Thx

Comment: tried, ",CAST(STR_VALUE AS varchar(50)) = NULL" but doesn't work..am I using wrong synt for such scenario?

Comment: Can u post a larger (not too large tho) query - how you intend to use the derived column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `CAST` it:

```
SELECT
INT_VALUE = CAST(NULL AS int)
,STR_VALUE = CAST(NULL as VARCHAR(10))
```

Comment: Ahh great! Thanks. I was using STR_Value inside cast before. :( Will makrk it as ans soon.

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` defaults to an int.  You can change it to any other type using `cast()`:

```
SELECT INT_VALUE = NULL, -- Result Data Type = INT
       STR_VALUE = cast(NULL as varchar(255)) -- Result Data Type = varchar(255)
```

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your answer to show what (I think) what you really meant

Comment: Thanks Gordon.Lamak for taking time and posting/explaining.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a table based on your SELECT (e.g. SELECT INTO) you can also use cast/convert:

```
SELECT NULL as INT_VALUE, CAST(NULL as Varchar(10)) AS STR_VALUE
INTO MyNewTable
```

Comment: Thanks Yuriy for taking time and posting/explaining. I am going to use this in ETL lookup query where I need to use SELECT statement (no variables or anything) and need to pass in NULL column. I could have created a derived STR NULL column separately but wanted to find out how to achieve this in T-SQl. :) Thx for the query.